# Docker doesn't have permission to execute bash file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elixir

I have followed a guide to dockerise an Elixir/Phoenix project and I created a bash script, but docker doesn't have permssion to execute the file. I ran

```
docker-compose build
chmod u+x entrypoint.sh 
docker-compose up
```

despite running the commands it still doesn't have permission. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `chmod + x ./entrypoint.sh` on **your machine** (not in docker file). But may be you have scripts inside your `entrypoint.sh` which can not be executed without `root` permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to do the `chmod` inside a custom Dockerfile, build your own image, and run it through docker-compose as shown below,

```
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
```

Doing it directly on the host works only if the docker compose is mounting that file as a volume bind when running the image..

Comment: Thank you that fixed it, putting that command right before running the file in the dockerfile made it work

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by VonC, you might need to create a custom docker image. Copy the file inside the image and then change the permission. You can look at an example of initializing a SQL Server 2017 database using entry point.sh at

https://www.handsonarchitect.com/2018/01/build-custom-sql-server-2017-linux.html